# Making a variable a 'less than' value?

Tags: python-3.x, variables

i'm really new to Python and am completely stuck

is there any way to make the less than value a variable

for example

```
x = int(input ("Input a value for x: "))
i = 1

while i < x:
    x += i
    i += 1
else:

    print ("here is your new number:", x,)
```

whenever i use this, nothing happens

thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "make the less than value of variable"? are you asking how to make value of x less than i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not technically true to say that nothing happens, plenty is happening.

However, *one* thing that's not happening is the thing that generates the output (unless you enter a value less than or equal to one).

The `while..else` construct will only execute the `else` block if the `while` block did not do any iterations.

So, if you want output after the loop regardless of whether the loop body executes, get rid of the `else` and unindent the `print`.

The *other* thing that's not happening is the exit condition of the loop itself. If `i` starts out less than `x` (and they're both positive to start with), adding `i` to `x` then adding `1` to `i` will never give you a situation where `i` is not less than `x`.

Think about (for example):

```
    x       i   Description
-----   -----   -----------
    3       1   Initial state
    4       2   x += i; i += 1;
    6       3   x += i; i += 1;
    9       4   x += i; i += 1;
   13       5   x += i; i += 1;
   18       6   x += i; i += 1;
   24       7   x += i; i += 1;
   31       8   x += i; i += 1;
```

You can see that `x` is increasing at a faster rate than `i`, hence `i < x` will always be true.

How you fix that depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve. Since you have described your problem in terms of the code, your code matches perfectly your requirements. Hence, since you state it's not working as you expected, it appears your requirements may need some work :-)

I would suggest stating, in *English,* what you're trying to achieve here, and we can then suggest where your implementation has gone wrong.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply, I've done that and it still doesn't output anything,
I'm sorry for such a basic question, I feel pretty stupid but I just cant make it work

Comment: @James, no problems, and no need to feel stupid. SO welcomes people at *all* skill levels, and you have at least tried to do something, which many questioners don't always do. That it's still not working is a subsequent problem which I have now addressed in the answer. Suggest you read it over and think about what your actual intent is with the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote will result in an infinite loop if i < x in the beginning. So it will never reach the print statement that you hope it will. Plus, I also believe that you have to delete the else and indent the print statement.